# Pythonic strategy to overwrite global variables in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

EDIT2:

Thanks for your help, problem solved, went with an intermediate approach:

[image]

Will accept the answer when it becomes eligible to be accepted!

---

EDIT:

I was asked for simpler variables, okay, I will try :)

Assume I want to have data in separate variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, how would I assign data to them in a for loop?

An approach like this:

```
a, b, c, d = [], [], [], []

for var,data in zip([a,b,c,d], some_data_array):
    var = #data that comes from some operation on data array
```

wouldn't work, the variables `a, b, c, d` would still be `[]`, since they are in the global scope.

---

I have a training dataset `train_set` (numpy array) that I want to reduce into smaller training datasets (90%, 80%, 70%, etc.).
I don't want to copy & paste the procedure

```
train_90perc = train_set[np.random.choice(train_set.shape[0],\
        train_set.shape[0] * 0.9, replace=False),:]
```

and thought I could do it with a for loop. But how? My initial approach (below) has the problem that it wouldn't modify the variables in the global scope. So when I would print e.g., `train_80perc` after the for loop, it would still be `[]`.
PS: The first 2 lines are to initialize the variables, is there also a way I can get around that (since it looks kind of ugly).

```
train_100perc, train_90perc, train_80perc, train_70perc, train_60perc, train_50perc,\
train_40perc, train_30perc, train_20perc, train_10perc = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

for train,size in zip([train_100perc, train_90perc, train_80perc,\
                       train_70perc, train_60perc, train_50perc,\
                       train_40perc, train_30perc, train_20perc, train_10perc],\
                       [p for p in reversed([i/10 for i in range(1,11)])]
                     ):
    #global train
    train = train_set[np.random.choice(train_set.shape[0],\
    train_set.shape[0] * size, replace=False),:]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you maybe simplify your question. Use simpler variables and a simpler explanation. You would have more success getting helpful answers.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I tried (Edit section on top of the initial question) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Don't assign some data to`var`. because it's just reference.

```
a, b, c, d = [], [], [], []

for var,data in zip([a,b,c,d], some_data_array):
    # call var.extend or var.append
    # var = some_value # don't do this. because it's just reference.
    var.extend(some_list)
```

---

Do you have to generate `train_100perc` ... ?

My suggestion is

```
subset = {}
for percent in np.arange(10, 100, 10):
    np.random.shuffle(train_set) # shuffle in-place
    subset[percent] = train_set[:len(train_set)*percent*0.01].copy() # selection of training data
```

`np.arange(10, 100, 10)` can vary.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot abut using a dictionary for storage -.-. You are right, train_100perc is kind of redundant, I can also make a deepcopy of the original array (I didn't mention it, but I do some modification downstream and would like to keep the original data for reference). I added my intermediate solution as an answer here. I don't know why, but the shuffle behaved weirdly.

Comment: `copy()` should be sufficient here, since I only stored floats in the arrays. However, I prefer to use `deepcopy()` to be on the save side and don't want to run into troubles if I make `copy()` a habit ;) ...in case I am using mutables some time.